# Qt5 MySQL driver not loaded - Windows

Tags: c++, qt5, mysql-connector

I want to connect to a MySQL database, only every time I try I get this error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
```

I tried to install **MariaDB-Connector-C** and **MySQL-Connector-Cpp**, but neither of them worked, I also tried to copy the file `libmariadb.lib` in the application build folder but it still gives error and I don't know how to do it, in the driver installation files are missing files with extension **.dll**.
I also tried to put the **.lib** files as libraries in the Qt project, but still nothing, it doesn't work, would you know how to fix it? Thank you.

Edit:

First I downloaded the MySql Connector for C from this link: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/

After I executed these commands:

```
C:\Qt5\5.13.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/lib"

mingw32-make

mingw32-make install
```

And now this comes out as a mistake:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMARIADB driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMARIADB QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Comment: Did you build it? I believe support for MYSQL is not enabled in the standard binaries for Qt

Comment: Related to the previous comment: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#compile-only-a-specific-sql-driver](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#compile-only-a-specific-sql-driver)

Comment: @drescherjm no, but if I go to `C:\Qt\5.15.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers` I see the folder **mysql**.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I did everything I described in the edit I solved it. Basically I went to QtCreator, added a new library to the project (`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\libmysql.lib`) and now everything works properly!